# Conditional transform of a Series subset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the cleanest way to do the following transformation in Pandas (Python) :

```
number   color
 10      blue
 15      red
 25      green
 35      blue
 15      pink
 30      green
  5      red
 20      blue
 50      red
```

into

```
number   color
 10      blue
 15      FALSE
 25      FALSE
 35      blue
 15      FALSE
 30      green
  5      FALSE
 20      blue
 50      red
```

Essentially, I'd like to change all colors whose number is < 30 but that rule only applies if the color IS NOT blue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach -

```
df.loc[(df.number < 30) & (df.color != 'blue'),'color'] = False
```

Sample run -

```
In [409]: df
Out[409]: 
   number  color
0      10   blue
1      15    red
2      25  green
3      35   blue
4      15   pink
5      30  green
6       5    red
7      20   blue
8      50    red

In [410]: df.loc[(df.number < 30) & (df.color != 'blue'),'color'] = False

In [411]: df
Out[411]: 
   number  color
0      10   blue
1      15  False
2      25  False
3      35   blue
4      15  False
5      30  green
6       5  False
7      20   blue
8      50    red
```

Comment: Fab ! That's great solution. Would something also work with .map()? Just curious.

Comment: @user2475110 Not really familiar with `map` based methods. I prefer vectorized methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of map, you can use "apply".  Apply runs the function on each row.

```
def mod_color(row) : 
    if row.number < 30 and row.color != 'blue': 
        row.color = False
    return row

df.apply(mod_color, axis=1)
```